# How to style a div of variable heights with inner and outer curved corners

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I was given this design with the part of the header that contains the logo taller than the rest, and a gradient throughout and inner shadow, but I can't conceive how to structure the CSS to get curves that follow the edge.

Screenshot of design:

[image: screenshot of design]

Comment: Understood. My attempts failed so thoroughly I didn't imagine them useful for feedback, in the future will present my code.

Comment: It’s quite difficult getting pure CSS to do this because of the way corners and shadows are rendered. I suspect it would look better and be more reliable to have the body in the pale blue and an image, preferably SVG, for the dark blue.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can based on this:

CSS:

```
.main {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -2px grey;
  display: flex;
}
.invisible {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 85px;
  background: cyan;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -2px grey;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="main">
       <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
       <div class="invisible"></div>
       <div>Bla Bla</div>
       <div>Bla Bla</div>
   </div>
</body>
```